# how to address the video in asp.net server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, video

I have developed a tiny website that works like youtube. people upload and watch videos. The website works fine in my local machine but when I put the site on IIS and try to click a video, It cannot find the video.

here is the html below. I am sure that test4.mp4 exists in the folder.

```
<video width='770' height='440' controls>
     <source src='uploaded_files/test5.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
     <source src='uploaded_files/test5.ogg' type='video/ogg'>
     <source src='uploaded_files/test5.webm' type='video/webm'>
     <object data='uploaded_files/test5.mp4' width='770' height='440'>
        <embed src='uploaded_files/test5.swf' width='770' height='440'>
     </object> 
</video>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are the videos stored in the paht you uploaded_files/... ?

Comment: yes,they are in uploaded_files/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then it's seems you have to configure properly you IIS. Please follow the following steps:

- Select the site to configure in IIS, right click and select "Properties"
- Under HTTP Headers Tab, select "File Types" under the MIME Map section and select "New Type"
- for .mp4 files type ".mp4" as the extension and "video/mp4" as the mime type
- Select "OK"
- type services.msc, find the "World Wide Web Publishing Service" and click on the restart icon on top or open up and choose restart